# could not print the file to pdf in firefox using this javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

**This function works fine in chrome but not in Firefox or internet Explorer**

```
function setPrint(tableId) {  
        var page = '<html><table border="1" style="border-spacing:0">' +   $j('#' + tableId).html() + '</table></html>';  
        w = window.open();  
        w.document.write(page);  
        w.print();  
    w.close();  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this problem. Here when it comes to internet Explorer JavaScript is not working properly. In Firefox there is no printing option as PDF but as a solution we can use **XPS** format. XPS is also like a PDF format but not the best option may be though. if it is for personal usage we can use some thing like cute PDF writer. but this cannot be used as a professional solution.